# incrontab $@ giving subdirectory and not watched directory

Tags: linux, operating-system, incron

/tmp/target_dir IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_TO /tmp/script.sh $@

contents of script.sh

```
echo $1 > /tmp/script.log
```

on executing

```
cp -r some_dir /tmp/target_dir
```

contents of /tmp/script.log

```
/tmp/target_dir
```

on executing

```
cp some_file /tmp/target_dir/some_dir
```

contents of /tmp/script.log

```
/tmp/target_dir/some_dir
```

here instead of watched directory directory on which work is done is echoed.
As far as i understand from [here](https://www.mankier.com/5/incrontab) $@ is used to display watched system path.

Comment: @Armali thnx, for pointing out it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as i understand from [here](https://www.mankier.com/5/incrontab) $@ is used to display watched system path.

Stated there is: *When monitoring a directory, the events marked with an asterisk (*) above can occur for files in the directory, in which case the name field in the returned event data identifies the name of the file within the directory.*

> instead of watched directory directory on which work is done is echoed.

The *directory on which work is done* is exactly the *file within the directory* as documented. (Copying `some_file` into `/tmp/target_dir/some_dir` has *modified* `/tmp/target_dir/some_dir`.)

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. I think I should pass the directory  as argument instead of passing it using wildcard

Comment: $@ is the wild card for passing the watched directory. As per documentation.